# Postgresql failed to start

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, ubuntu

I am trying to use PostgreSQL on Ubuntu. I installed it and everything was working fine. However, I needed to change the  location of my database due to space constraints so I tried an online guide to do it.

I proceeded to stop postgresql, create a new empty directory and give it permissions by using

```
chown postgres:postgres /my/dir/path
```

That worked fine too. Then I used

```
initdb -D /my/dir/path
```

to enable my database. I also changed the path_data in the `postgresql.conf` file to my new directory.

When I now try to start the database, it says: `The postgresql server failed to start, please check the log file`. However, there is no log file! Something got screwed up when I changed the default directory. How do I fix this?

Comment: Please include basic information like your Ubuntu and PostgreSQL version, and the exact text of any error messages.

Comment: You got poor answers to this question because it lacks the minimum reasonable amount of information. "An online guide"? Which one. Link to it. When you say you edited `postgresql.conf` - where was that file? `/etc/postgresql/` ? Your datadir? When you "try to start the database" - using *which exact command* ? Show error messages and exact commands. Be detailed and specific.

Comment: Reposted as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608482/postgresql-changing-data-directory-in-ubuntu  and reposted *again* as http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/21312/postgresql-changing-data-directory-in-ubuntu .

Answer (score 4):

First: You may find it easier to manage your Pg installs on Ubuntu using the custom tools Ubuntu provides as part of [`pg_wrapper`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/pg_wrapper.1.html): [`pg_createcluster`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pg_createcluster.8.html), [`pg_dropcluster`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pg_dropcluster.8.html), [`pg_ctlcluster`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man8/pg_ctlcluster.8.html) etc. These integrate with the Ubuntu startup scripts and move the configuration to `/etc/postgresql/` where Ubuntu likes to keep it, instead of the PostgreSQL default of in the datadir. To move where the actual files are stored, use a symbolic link (see below).

When you have a problem, how are you starting PostgreSQL?

If you're starting it via `pg_ctl` it should work fine because you have to specify the data directory location. If you're using your distro package scripts, though, they don't know you've moved the data directory.

On Ubuntu, you will need to change configuration in `/etc/postgresql` to tell the scripts where the data dir is, probably `pg_ctl.conf` or `start.conf` for the appropriate version. I'm not sure of the specifics as I've never needed to do it. This is why:

There's a better way, though. Use a symbolic link from your old datadir location to the new one. PostgreSQL and the setup scripts will happily follow it and you won't have to change any configuration.

```
cd /var/lib/postgresql/9.1/main
mv main main.old
ln -s /new/datadir/location main
```

I'm guessing "9.1" because you didn't give your Ubuntu version or your PostgreSQL version.

An alternative is to use `mount -o bind` to map your new datadir location into the old place, so nothing notices the difference. Then add the bind mount to `/etc/fstab` to make it persistent across reboots. You only need to do that if one of the tools doesn't like the symbolic link approach. I don't think that'll be an issue with `pg_wrapper` etc.

You should also note that since you've used initdb manually, your new datadir will have its configuration directly inside the datadir, not in `/etc/postgresql/`.

It's way easier if you just use the Ubuntu cluster management scripts instead.