# Postgresql changing data directory in ubuntu

Tags: sql, postgresql, ubuntu, terminal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Postgresql failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562590/postgresql-failed-to-start)

This problem has been driving me crazy and nothing seems to be working. I need to change the location where postgresql stores the data base. I am a complete novice when it comes to using commands in the terminal and step by step instructions with the proper commands would really help. I searched all over the web but all instructions assume some prior good knowledge to terminal commands. I did try one approach by creating a symbolic link in the main data folder to my required location. This gives me an error that asks me to check the log file. However, I have no idea where the log file is. A lot of people seem to have this problem and a step by step solution would surely help. My Psql version is 8.4. Ubuntu 10.10

Comment: Do you have you existing contents that need to be moved or are you considering a clean empty instance?

Comment: Also a re-post of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562590/postgresql-failed-to-start

Comment: I deleted the question on DBA.  @Amitash, if you cross-post again like this there will probably be consequences.  **Don't do it.**

Answer (score 27):

The latest log file full path is `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-8.4-main.log` but the symbolic link is not the more integrated/easy way to change the data location.

I'd suggest to do it by creating the entire cluster to the desired location, with the [pg_createcluster](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/pg_createcluster.8.html) command that comes with the debian/ubuntu postgres packages.

1- delete your current cluster, if it does not contain any prior data:

> ```
> $ sudo pg_dropcluster --stop 8.4 main
> ```

2- create a new cluster at the new location

> ```
> $ sudo pg_createcluster -d /path/to/new/location 8.4 main
> ```

3- restart postgresql

> ```
> $ sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
> ```

Comment: Cluster drops perfectly. When I try to create a new cluster on my second hard drive, it says "initdb permission denied". So I did a chown on my user on my folder. That worked fine. When I try again, I still get the same error. Is this maybe because I am trying to create the cluster in a mounted drive and not my root ubuntu installation drive?

Comment: Creating new cluster (configuration: /etc/postgresql/8.4/main, data: /media/New Volume/Virulence/data)...
could not change directory to "/media/New Volume/Virulence"
initdb: could not access directory "/media/New Volume/Virulence/data": Permission denied
Error: initdb failed

Comment: @Amitash: When executed with `sudo`  pg_createcluster should fix directories and permissions by itself. _BUT_: When you talk about a `/media` path: Is this a removable device? Is is by chance a FAT or NTFS filesystem? Then permissions won't work.

Comment: It looks like the permissions of the folder do not let the `postgres` user descend into that directory. Make sure that all directories in the path have the 'x' bit set for other user (for example rwxr-xr-x is good, rwx------ is not good). Do `chmod -R 755 /media` if you don't know how to fine-tune it.

Comment: @Amitash: you are aware that dropcluster deletes all your existing data?

Comment: @a-h Yea it is NTFS and was created in windows. Is there anyway I can further split this partition in ubuntu? There is a lot of free space here which I want to use in ubuntu.

Comment: Not sure if you can shrink and repartition, but [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) would be the place to ask.

Comment: @Amitash Things like "It is NTFS and was created in Windows" is kind of *important*. Please post detailed questions to save everybody the time of asking you for every detail.

Comment: I have the same Issue with 9.1 on ubuntu 13.04: pg_create cluster fails with permission denied.