# PostgreSql 9.3 initdb

Tags: database, postgresql

I am trying to log an application using postgresql and I want to use a database in a place other then where the installation creates it.  I have done this several times in the past, but I guess postgresql has changed.  The message told me I had to install some clustering solution, all I want to do is change to another database solution.

Is there a way to initialize a database in postgresql other then initdb and postgres-xc.

Also, pg_ctl is now only available on postgres-xs.  I don't need a clustering solution, I just need to move the database location.

Comment: If using Ubuntu you probably want to read: [Postgresql changing data directory in ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11608918/238814). This was written for 8.4 but it applies to 9.3 as well.

Comment: Or [Missing the pg_ctl package in Postgres 9.3 installation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11608918/238814) on dba.se which mentions the confusing hints about postgres-xc.